# When is a call to "RUN ln" able to be cached by Docker?

Tags: docker

I have the following result from `docker build .`.  Why doesn't Docker ever seem to cache step 4?  Can I make it use cache with some tweak?

(The rest of the file as far as I know is irrelevant, but this failure to cache also results in steps 5 and following to build without cache.)

```
+ docker build .


Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.678MB

Step 1/36 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as builder
 ---> c4155a9104a8

Step 2/36 : ARG branch_build_commit
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2a8f43280a27

Step 3/36 : WORKDIR /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3bf42ec98ab

Step 4/36 : RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime && echo America/Chicago > /etc/timezone
 ---> Running in 32bd1e2cff9e
Removing intermediate container 32bd1e2cff9e
 ---> 8d49354c0de6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile documentation notes, under [Impact [of ARG] on build caching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching):

> ...all `RUN` instructions following an `ARG` instruction use the `ARG` variable implicitly (as an environment variable), thus can cause a cache miss.

If this is in the context of a CI system and each build is normally passed a `docker build --build-arg branch_build_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD) .` or something similar, then every build will have a different `ARG` value and `RUN` instructions will *always* cause a cache miss.

On the other hand, it's merely convention that `ARG` comes early in a Dockerfile so that it can be found.  The Dockerfile documentation on [Scope [of ARG]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope) has some specific notes that `ARG` values can only be used after the `ARG` statement, and has an example of `ARG` not being first.  So you can make caching work again by moving the `ARG` statement later in the file:

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as builder
# These statements don't use the ARG value so they can come first.
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime && echo America/Chicago > /etc/timezone
# Then you can declare the ARG value later
ARG branch_build_commit
# And any uses must come after the ARG statement.
RUN echo ${branch_build_commit:-unknown} > /etc/build-version
```